# How to drop rows containing NA in specified columns?

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a dataframe like this

```
      dep_delay  temp  humid wind_dir precip pressure  date
16983  3         68.00 53.06 NA       0      1020.8    2013-05-07 

26477  42        NA  64.93 360      0        NA        2013-03-07
...
29299  -1        NA    NA    NA       NA     NA        2013-12-31 

29300  33        NA    NA    NA       NA     NA        2013-12-31
```

I want to drop only the rows like 29299 and 29300, which contain 5 `NA`s from temp to pressure (these are consecutive columns), and keep the rows like 16983 and 26477.

desired result:

```
      dep_delay  temp  humid wind_dir precip pressure  date
16983  3         68.00 53.06 NA       0      1020.8    2013-05-07 

26477  42        NA  64.93 360      0        NA        2013-03-07
```

In other words, the problem is how to remove only the rows where there are at least 5 `NA`s in a row.

apparently this is not the right way to do it:

```
df <- df[!is.na(df$temp:df$pressure),]
```

Comment: You want to exclude rows which have NA for each of the 5 variables or for consecutive variables?

Comment: df[complete.cases(df[, c("temp", "humid", "wind_dir", "precip", "pressure")]), ]

Comment: @YacineHajji, your code returns empty data frame. Since complete.cases return TRUE only when all variables are not NA.

Comment: You are right, then it is `df[rowSums(is.na(df[, c("temp", "humid", "wind_dir", "precip", "pressure")])) != ncol(df[, c("temp", "humid", "wind_dir", "precip", "pressure")]), ]` but I guess your answer is already sufficient. Creating a vector for variables name would simplify this row.

Comment: @YacineHajji, thanks I'll correct the answer in accordance with your recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated based on Yacine Jajji comment.

You can use standard `filter` function in `dplyr` package. You set the number of columns which should be never `NA`. In your case there are `2`: `dep_delay` and `date`. Then calculate amount of `NA` in each row, if the number equals `5` the row will be filtered out. See the code below:

```
df <- read.table( text = "dep_delay  temp  humid wind_dir precip pressure  date
16983  3         68.00 53.06 NA       0      1020.8    2013-05-07 
26477  42        NA  64.93 360      0        NA        2013-03-07
29299  -1        NA    NA    NA       NA     NA        2013-12-31 
29300  33        NA    NA    NA       NA     NA        2013-12-31")

library(dplyr)

cols_to_remove <- c("temp", "humid", "wind_dir", "precip", "pressure")
df[rowSums(is.na(df[, cols_to_remove])) != 
     ncol(df[, cols_to_remove]), ]
```

Output:

```
      dep_delay temp humid wind_dir precip pressure       date
16983         3   68 53.06       NA      0   1020.8 2013-05-07
26477        42   NA 64.93      360      0       NA 2013-03-07
```